# Default move constructor Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

There seems to be conflicting documentation as to whether Visual Studio 2015 supports generation of default move constructors.

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx) and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) seem say to no, whereas [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx) says yes.

I tried something simple:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test(int data) : data(data) {}
    Test(Test&& other) = default;
    Test(Test& other) = delete;
    int data;
};

int main() {
    Test c(3);
    std::cout << c.data << std::endl;
    Test b(std::move(c));
    std::cout << b.data << std::endl;
}
```

It prints out 3 and 3 as expected. Am I making some mistake or is the default move constructor actually being generated?

Edit: Removed "implicit" wording

Comment: In the example you explicitly ask for defaulted move and copy constructors, i.e. they are not implicitly generated, so if you want to test implicitly generated constructors then your program doesn't do that.

Comment: Err yeah, the "implicit" part is not needed, I just want to know if default move constructors are supported, I'll edit the question.

Comment: The second link seems to say [Yes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#tableguide): *""Rvalue references v3.0" adds new rules to automatically generate move constructors and move assignment operators under certain conditions. This is implemented in Visual Studio 2015."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The move constructor is being generated. It just happens that moving an `int` is achieved by copying (setting the "moved" object to some other value would be more expensive than just leaving it as is.)

You could test this by using a verbose movable type as data member instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The two links you say are telling you 'no' are telling you 'yes'.

Visual Studio 2015 supports `default` and `deleted` functions.
That's very clearly stated in the second link I think.

There is a tiny bit of potential confusion in the way C++ uses the word 'default'.

In most common circumstances we understand asking for the default is to get what you would have got anyway - nothing special.

But in these circumstances it actually means 'reintroduce the default implementation'.

That is:

```
Test(Test&& other) = default;
```

Doesn't mean 'do the default thing in respect of the move constructor which is provide or don't provide it based of other features of the class'.

It means 'do provide the default implementation of the move constructor even if it wouldn't (by default) be provided based on other features of the class'.

Read the `=` as saying 'assign this to its default implementation' not 'do the default thing here.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The first link says: "Visual Studio does not support defaulted move constructors or move-assignment operators as the C++11 standard mandates." And the second link says "Defaulted and Deleted Functions.
These are now supported, but with this exception: For defaulted functions, the use of =default to request member-wise move constructors and move assignment operators is not supported." Doesn't that imply default generation is not supported?

Comment: @newprogrammer I think your code shows the defaulted move constructor is generated. Or do you have another possible interpretation for the fact that it compiles? Also, as I mentioned in my answer, the test output isn't very meaningful. The only test is that the code compiles.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes i tried it with a verbose type, the move constructor is definitely being used, not the copy constructor.

Comment: @newprogrammer In subtle ways not related to what you're doing. In fact I read it as saying it will implement members that the standard wants deleted by default. Your code explicitly instantiates the defaults.